# Interaction between ios::app and an fstream used for input

Tags: c++, io, append, iostream, fstream

While debugging someone else's code I came across an interaction between C++'s `fstream` object, input via the stream operator and `ios::app` which I was not previously aware of.

Assume `file.txt` exists and contains textual data. The `fstream` in its original context was long lived and served for both input and output. The following code does not work as expected (provides no output from the file), error handling code has been omitted:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream f("file.txt", ios::app);
    string in;
    f >> in;
    cout << in << endl;
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Changing the file open statement to the following resolves the issue:

```
fstream f("file.txt");
```

Is this expected behaviour? Should it not be possible to open an `fstream` object with ios::app and expect input via the stream operators to behave correctly?

Compiled with g++ 4.6.3 on 64-bit Linux and mingw-g++ 4.4.1 on 32-bit Windows 7

Comment: This toy example was created after removing several items from the Murphy Set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [`std::fstream` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) you will note that the default argument is a bitfield of the flags `ios_base::in` and `ios_base::out`. By supplying only `ios_base::app` as the flag you make the file append-only. If you want *both* input and append, then you have to use e.g. `ios::in | ios::app`.

Comment: Ah yes, I was aware of this but neglected to consider that the default behaviour for fstream (ios::in | ios::out) is set by way of a default value for the parameter rather than as present values for whatever data members store the options. In most implementations I guess it would probably just store the parameter and re-test with & as needed to save space.